# 3D tube one side black

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js

I am drawing 3D tube with three.js

I am seeing one side of that tube black. Please help me for the same

Please find code at: http://jsfiddle.net/7WNZ7/ `Code at above link`

Comment: Your fiddle renders nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some ambient light like so:

```
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x888888 );
scene.add( light );
```

And you need to add `ambient` reflectance to your material. It will also look better if the material is double-sided:

```
var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, 
    [new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: color, 
        ambient: color, 
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    }), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x000000,
        wireframe: true,
        transparent: false
    })
]);
```

Alternatively, you could just add more directional or point lights.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WNZ7/1/

Comment: hi @WestLangley thanks for your reply. I am also looking for implementing pan functionality for traversing along the path of pipe and displaying tooltip on click only on pipe which displays the actual length of pipe upto that particular point.

Can you please help me for that.

Comment: If you have another issue, please make a new post. Describe what you have tried (or provide a jsfiddle), and ask a single, specific question. That is the best way to get further help if you need it. Good luck!